# How do I get the string in a column in sed?

Tags: sed

I have a text file which has words separated by a tab. Some lines might not have a word in the second column and same goes to the third column. How do I get words in the 2nd and 3rd column in sed (if they exist)?

```
abc   cde   def
abc         his
abc   rat
```

How to obtain cde and def? his? rat?

Here's what I've tried

```
sed 's/^.*\([^\t]\)$/\1/'
```

But I got an empty output

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `cut -f2-` cuts out the 1st fileld, is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep it simple

`sed 's/^[^\t]*\t//' table.txt`

Substitute first column with the following `\t` character, with an empty string.
This will result only the relevant columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$2{printf("%s\n",$2)}$3{printf("%s\n",$3)}' file
```

Comment: @llamaro25 as you see of other post, it can be done with `sed`.  Do you not have `awk` as well in your system?

Answer (score 0):

Sed answer that handles 1 column, 4 columns, etc:

`sed -E 's/[^\t]*(\t|$)//;s/(([^\t]*(\t|$)){1,2}).*/\1/'`

Remove the first, perhaps only, column.  Prune to 1st and 2nd column of what's left.

This is very much an `awk` or `cut` issue though.

In perl, there's this: `perl -lne 'print join "\t", (split /\t/)[1..2]'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to achieve this, but just offering a simpler approach using cut

```
cut -d$'\t' -f'2,3' table.txt

# or
# Press Ctrl+V and then Tab when entering delimiter character

cut -d' ' -f'2-3' table.txt
```